# Change shortcut for completing suggestion

Tags: visual-studio-2013, resharper

When I start typing on a new line in method body a suggestion pops up. When I hit space, the suggestion is automatically applied. This is something I am not very used to.

Is is possible to unregister space from such action ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep. ReSharper -> Options -> IntelliSense -> Completing Characters and uncheck "Complete on space" for the language you're interested in.